# Problem in animation of progressbar in QT

Tags: qt, animation, qt4, symbian, progress-bar

i did progress bar in QT, i used both in emulator and mobile..
the infinite progress bar in appearing but its not getting animated.. (infinite progress is not coming)

here is the code which i hv written

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();

dialog->setMinimum(0);
dialog->setMaximum(0);

dialog->showMaximized(); 
dialog->exec();   
return a.exec();
```

pls suggest if some thing wrong

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code provided, so if it acts that way, I would consider it a bug with the Qt code, and submit a bug report (probably with the code you gave above as a sample program to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a blank project with QTCreator and Qt 4.6.1 and it worked...

Maybe you could try to add this line : qApp->processEvents();

Hope it helps a bit!

Edit : And if you try to remove the line dialog->exec(); I don't think it's necessary...

Comment: I usually doubt the use of qApp->processEvents(), and especially in this case... he does all of this setup, then calls a.exec() -- which is telling the QApplication object to run its event loop.  So it should already be processing events.

Comment: Hey andy, it works fine if i create in QT creator runs well for my desktop dialog application.
but i tried same for symbian application its not working only..
i dont no exact reason.. can u pls help me in this.

Comment: Well, as Caleb said, maybe you shoud consider it as a bug... Report it on Qt bug tracker, they're pretty reactive... I hope they'll fix your problem quickyl !

Comment: Andy it got fixed..
its bug in QT 4.6.0..
its fixed in QT 4.6.2